# How do I write a AMPscript RetrieveRequest that counts all records and not just 2500?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

I need to count all matching records for a RetrieveRequest on the ListSubscribers object via AMPscript on a landing page. I got it to count the first 2500 rows by using this code. How do I get it to count the rest of the rows?

I found a method using the soap api and php on [this page](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-more-than-2500-records-using-the-continuerequest-property.html), but how do I achieve this with pure AMPscript?

```
SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")  
    SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "ListSubscriber")  
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","SubscriberKey")  
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","Status")    

Set @sf1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"Property","ListID")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"SimpleOperator","equals")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1,"Value","2830313")

Set @sf2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"Property","Status")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"SimpleOperator","equals")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf2,"Value","Active")

Set @cf1 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sf1)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sf2)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")

SetObjectProperty(@rr, "Filter", @cf1)  

SET @subs = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @statusOutput, @requestId)  

SET @activecount = RowCount(@subs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to capture the ContinueRequest property and use it again to retrieve the remaining rows.

There's an example on this page:

[Retrieving More than 2500 Records Using the ContinueRequest Property](http://help.exacttarget.com/pt/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/continuerequest_2500records/)

It's in C#, but it'll get you going down the right path with the AMPScript you have so far:

```
do
{
    status = client.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out Results);

    Console.WriteLine("Total Records: " + Results.Length);

    //Display Results
    for (int i = 0; i < Results.Length; i++)
    {
        sEvent = (SentEvent)Results[i];

        Console.WriteLine("SubKey on Event: " + sEvent.SubscriberKey);
    }

    //This call the API again to get the next 2500 records
    rr = new RetrieveRequest();
    rr.ContinueRequest = requestID;
} while (status.Equals("MoreDataAvailable"));
```